# How can I remove automatic Google Cloud Firestore indexes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a small web application that uses Firestore for the data.
I am currently storing around 8 million objects.

The data size in the Firestore database is 10 times bigger than it is in "raw" format (json files).

Reading [this wiki](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) I came to the conclusion that there is a high chance that the automatic indexes are guilty of the humongous size of the database.

I have read the [indexing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) and it says how to create and remove custom indexes from the console, but I haven't find a way of removing automatic indexes.

Since I am only doing direct access to the objects, I don't need fields indexing at all.

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible.  Sounds like a feature request.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: This was added as of Aug 8th 2018 https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/more-cloud-firestore-improvements.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the Beta there is no way to remove automatic generated indexes in Firestore.

So far you are only able to manage composite indexes by yourself.

Source: A Google Firestore employee mentioned this as a part of an answer on another question on Stackoverflow. Though, I can't find the link to the post anymore.